# Output SQL table as csv using python not displaying correct decimal places

Tags: python, sql, csv, notepad, decimalformat

I am trying to output a table in SQL ([dbo].[temporary_table]) as a csv. There are 2 columns that contain numbers rounded to 4 decimal places but I want to output them rounded to 2 decimal places.

This is the SQL table I want to output as csv:

[image]

And this is the python code I'm using to output that table as csv:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd 
import xlsxwriter
import csv

sql_conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={DRIVER_NAME}; SERVER=SERVER_NAME; DATABASE=DATABASE_NAME; Trusted_Connection=yes') 

query = """select  [Name]
                   ,cast([Debits] as decimal(19,2)) as 'Debits'
                  ,cast([Credits] as decimal(19,2)) as 'Credits'
                  from [dbo].[temporary_table]"""
  
                                    
df = pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn)

file_out = 'C:\\Desktop\\Outputs\\testfile.csv'

df.to_csv(file_out, index = False, header=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

When I open the csv file in Notepad only the last 2 rows are rounded correctly. I'm guessing this is because the decimal places are not 0s. Is there a way to get the first row to be 50.00 and not just 50.0?

This is what I see when I open the csv file in Notepad:

[image]

And this is what I want:

[image]

If anyone is able to help I'd be very grateful.

Comment: `select cast(round([Debits], 2) as decimal(19, N2))`

Answer (score 2):

Pandas to_csv has a float_format argument that will force float dtypes in the dataframe to the specified format.

```
df.to_csv(file_out, index = False, float_format="%.2f", header=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Links to [pandas.to_csv docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) and [string format docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatspec), but seems like "%.2f" is what you need.